# Multiple gradients within each bar of stacked bar chart

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm having trouble creating a stacked bar graph with multiple gradients of colors in each bar.

Some sample data:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(magrittr)

df <-
    data.frame(person = rep(1:3, each = 30),
               drug_type = rep(rep(1:3, each = 10),3),
               drug = rep(1:30,times=3),
               sales_pct = rep(.033, times = 90)) %>%
    as_tibble()
```

There are three `persons` and 30 `drugs`, each of which is one of 3 `drug_types`.

What I would like to do is to show the each drug's fraction of each person's sales and to use color to visually segment the drugs into groups. I am trying to to this with one bar for each `person`, and, within each person's bar, each `drug_type` has its own color palette. So, drug_type `1` would, for example, be a spectrum of blues, `2` a spectrum of greens, etc.

Any advice? Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Is this kind of what you had in mind?

```
library(tidyverse)
library(magrittr)

df <- as.tibble(data.frame(person = rep(1:10, each = 3),
         drug_type = rep(1:10, times = 3),
         sales_pct = rep(.1, times = 30))) %>% 
      mutate(person = as.factor(person),
         drug_type = as.factor(drug_type))

ggplot(df, aes(x = person)) +
  geom_bar(aes(fill = drug_type)) + 
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,3)) +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Spectral")
```

[image]

Comment: No, but that is my fault for writing the mock data hurriedly. Thank you for the quick answer! I've edited the original post to hopefully be more precise and clear.

Comment: The sales_pct is the same for every single person regardless of drug_type. There won't be much variation when you try graphing it.

Comment: Yes, there’s more variation in the real data. But if I can get it working on the fake data then hopefully it should translate to the full data.